# python subtracting timedeltas in seconds

Tags: python

I need to subtract timedeltas in python and return the number in just a second form.

I currently have:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
q1_start_time = datetime.now()
q1_end_time = datetime.now()
total_time = q1_end_time - q1_start_time
print(total_time)
```

This returns:

```
0:00:01.549000
```

How can I get it to just return 1, or best case scenario it would return 2 ( rounding up ). I don't need 0:00:01 just need 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
print(total_time.total_seconds())
```

It's available for objects of type `datetime.timedelta` since Python 2.7.

`math.ceil()` is used to round floats to the next greater/equal integer number. Other rounding functions are `math.floor()`, and `round()`. If it's just about beautifying the printed representation of the number, you could also use Python's string formatting functionality, e.g.,

```
print "elapsed: %.2f seconds" % (t_end-t_start).total_seconds()
```

For reference:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds
- http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: Apply `round()` to round it to an integer.

Comment: is there awuick formatting way to get rid of the decimal?

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying You can round it, or you can use string formatting to beautify the output of that number.